# RPC program gets de-registered

Tags: rpc, x86

I am deploying my `ONC-RPC` application in `Solaris x86` platform for the first time.
It was working for years in `Solaris SPARC` platform.

I am seeing a weird issue.

When I start my main process, rpc program is registered, which I can see in `rpcinfo`.

```
536870992    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.76.169      -          500
```

When I check the status of the program, I am getting this error:

`rpcinfo -T tcp localhost 536870992`
`rpcinfo: RPC: Program not registered`

When I start another process, the previous rpc program got de-registered.

This is what I see in `rpcinfo`

```
program version   netid             address     service      owner
1073742167    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.79.169      -          500
 536871232    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.80.169      -          500
```

I have a doubt that there is some address conflict.
`0.0.0.0.76.169` and `0.0.0.0.80.169` share the same last field `169`.

How is address assigned and who assigns it?
What is its relevance?

Comment: the tcp net address is something like a.b.c.d.N.M, where a.b.c.d it the ip address, to which service is bound, and N.M in the port number as (N << 8) + M. In your case it ports 20649 and 20393. My question is why your program get's different program numbers after restart?

Comment: @tigran The second one is a different program and hence the number is different. My issue is the program is showing as not registered, when I check the status using `rpcinfo`. One difference I noticed is that in `SPARC` machine the addresses for each program used to have unique `M` value and maybe same `N` value. But in `x86` machine, they have unique `N` value and same `M` value. Is this because of some endianness issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. I was facing endianness issues because of the new `x86` platform.
I used `htons` and `ntohs` while setting/getting port from system level RPC structures to solve the issue. Now the program is successfully registered with port mapper.